# Parsing table with Jsoup

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I am new to android and Jsoup scene and have a small problem converting a table.
using for example this link
http://mywheels.ie/car-history-check/free-car-check-results/?VRN=00C31865
how can I parse the table and display the elements from the right hand side FIAT,RED,PETROL in the Log ? Thank you in advance

Comment: So far I was able of getting the website title, but don't really know how to use the table. I don't know how to address the table to get its content. If i had a small chunk of code that would display at least on element, i would be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupTest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<table><tr class='eventTableRow'><td id='1' class='class1'>value1</td><td id='2' class='class2'>value2</td><td id='3' class='class3'>value3</td></tr></table>");
        Elements row = doc.select(".eventTableRow td");
        Iterator<Element> iterator = row.listIterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Element element = iterator.next();
            String id = element.attr("id");
            String classes = element.attr("class");
            String value = element.text();
            System.out.println("Id : " + id + ", classes : " + classes+ ", value : " + value);
        }
    }

}
```

Via https://stackoverflow.com/users/159793/newbie